# How to identify and Remove any type of Bullet in the Text

Tags: javascript, regex

I am copyig some data from the MS Word. That text may contain or May not contain Bullets in the copied text. But i need a Regular expression in javascript to remove any type of Bullets from the copied text.
for example if i copy the text which is having bullets it is coming like this when i paste it.
Here are some examples

```
 1.   Jnflkvkbfjvb
 2.   Kjnfbhvjbv
 3.   ;kbvrjvbrjvb 

 •    Jnflkvkbfjvb  
 •    Kjnfbhvjbv  
 •    ;kbvrjvbrjvb  

 a)   Jnflkvkbfjvb
 b)   Kjnfbhvjbv
 c)   ;kbvrjvbrjvb 

 A.   Jnflkvkbfjvb
 B.   Kjnfbhvjbv
 C.   ;kbvrjvbrjvb 

  I.      Jnflkvkbfjvb
 II.      Kjnfbhvjbv
III.      ;kbvrjvbrjvb
```

But My requirement is to display without any of these bullets.It has to display

```
       Jnflkvkbfjvb
       Kjnfbhvjbv
       ;kbvrjvbrjvb
```

My code is

```
      var  x=" •    Jnflkvkbfjvb•    Kjnfbhvjbv•    ;kbvrjvbrjvb 1.     Jnflkvkbfjvb2.    Kjnfbhvjbv3.    ;kbvrjvbrjvb ";
      x= x.replace(/[•\t.+]/g, ''); 
      x= x.replace(/[[1-9][.]\t.+]/g, '');
      alert(x);
```

Please someone help me.
You can use this to edit the code
      http://jsfiddle.net/V2aSg/

Comment: I Have been trying it.. But as of now it is removing only round bullets.

Comment: what code have you tried? Could you add it as well?

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/V2aSg/5/) you want.

Comment: @Asad Rasheed yes, But please modify your code to make it also work  by identifying automatically.Any type of bullet...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
/^\s*(?:[\dA-Z]+\.|[a-z]\)|•)\s+/gm
```

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u326)

This checks

`^` The start of the row (with the modifier `m`)

`\s*` any amount of whitespace

`[\dA-Z]+\.` At least one (`+`) digit or `A-Z` followed by a dot

or

`[a-z]\)` `a-z` followed by a `)`

or

`•`

`\s+` At least one whitespace at last

Comment: +100 for explaining it. Regex confuses the hell out of me when it gets more advanced.

Comment: @Jam: This is still far from advanced. ;-)

Comment: Nice solution @stema, But it works for one level of auto-numbered list like 

1.   Content
2.   Content

but not for multiple levels like

1. Content
1.1. Sub-content
1.1.1.  Sub-Sub-content
1.1.1.1. Sub-Sub-Sub-content
2. Content

Comment: Great, although doesn't catch dashes.

Comment: It doesn't catches circle bullets, like o.

Answer (score 0):

If we need it for multiple auto-numbered list like

1. Content

   1.1. Content and so on 1.1.1...

Then this regex would `(.*?)\d\.\s+|[a-z]\)\s+|•\s+|o\s+|[A-Z]\.\s+|[IVX]+\.\s+|[ivx]+\.\s+`

Also, in my case i did not need the empty lines to be replaced/highlighted

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7aZgo/2)

Comment: This will remove all alphabet 'o' followed by a space. For example, 'o '